# Finding the max sum of n consecutive numbers where sum < k

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, time-complexity, max

I am given an array and asked to find the maximum possible sum of `n` consecutive numbers, where the maximum sum is less than a given value `k`.
For example:

```
array = {1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1}
k = 7
```

Here, the answer must be **6**, because the max sum that we can obtain that is *less than 7* is: `arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3] = 3 + 1 + 2 = 6`
How can I write an algorithm to find such a value?

(I have done it with a nested `for` loop, but it takes too much time, is there any other way to make this program work?)

Comment: Use a sliding window approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic Foundation**

First off, I'd suggest you read up a bit more about time complexity. There are enough good resources out there, and [Complexity Theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/complexity-theory/) is one of them. This should help you understand why your solution is not fast enough.

**O(n^3) Solution**

A brute-force approach is to check all possible subarrays, by iterating over the start and end points of the subarray, and adding up all elements in between.

Given an array `arr` of size `n`, the way to do that would be as follows:

```java
for (int l = 0; l < n; ++l) {
    for (int r = l; r < n; ++r) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int pos = l; pos <= r; ++pos) {
            sum += arr[pos];
        }
        if (sum < k)
            max = Math.max(max, sum);
    }
}
```

The final answer is stored in `max`.

**O(n^2) Solution**

A faster solution would eliminate the third loop by making use of [prefix sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). This can be done as follows, with the help of an auxiliary array `preSum` of the same size as the main array, where `preSum[i]` stores the sum of the first `i` elements:

```java
preSum[0] = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    preSum[i] = preSum[i - 1] + arr[i];
for (int l = 0; l < n; ++l) {
    for (int r = l; r < n; ++r) {
        long sum = preSum[r];
        if (l > 0)
            sum -= preSum[l - 1];
        if (sum < k)
            max = Math.max(max, sum);
    }
}
```

**O(n) solution**

The most efficient solution to this problem uses a *sliding window*/*two-pointer* approach. Note that we assume that negative numbers are not allowed.

We start with both `l` and `r` at the beginning of the array. There are two possible cases at every stage:

1. Sum of the current subarray `<k`: We can be hopeful and try to add more elements to the subarray. We do this by moving `r` one step further to the right.
2. Sum of the current subarray `>=k`: We need to remove some elements to make the sum satisfy the given constraint. This can be done by moving `l` one step to the right.

This is repeated till we hit we need to increment `r`, but have reached the end of the array. The code looks something like this:

```java
long max = 0;
int l = 0;
int r = 0;
long sum = arr[0];
    while (true) {
    if (sum >= k) {
        sum -= arr[l];
        ++l;
    } else {
        if (r == n - 1)
            break;
        else {
            ++r;
            sum += arr[r];
        }
    }
    if (sum < k)
        max = Math.max(max, sum);
}
```

Comment: Edited answer to add some more clarity. Let me know if it helps, or if you need more info somewhere.